# Azure load balancer unstable performance

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-cloud-services

I have cloud service with single worker role running self hosted web api.
Trying to consume this web api from another cloud service (in same vnet) using xxx.cloudapp.net address. But performance is very unstable. Sometimes after couple hundred requests, http requests freezes for some time. Seams like Azure load balancer is throttling my requests.

Here is output from Apache Bench with reproduced freezing (ran from another VM in same vnet):

```
ab -c 10 -n 1000 http://xxx.cloudapp.net/ping
<..>    
Time taken for tests:   39.970 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        1
   (Connect: 1, Receive: 0, Length: 0, Exceptions: 0)
<..>
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   19 402.6      0    9017
Processing:     0  360 2307.4     15   21046
Waiting:        0  318 2178.6      0   21046
Total:          0  379 2339.6     16   21046

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     16
  66%     16
  75%     16
  80%     16
  90%     16
  95%     17
  98%   9015
  99%   9032
 100%  21046 (longest request)
```

There are not freezes when using local IP (e.g. 10.0.0.x).
Tried using web role/iis with same results.

Why this is happening? How to avoid this? I don't want to use local IP, because then I will loose swapping feature.

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, since it's infrastructure, and not programming. That said - have you attempted to benchmark your api calls using ip address instead of dns name, to eliminate potential dns resolution issues?

Comment: Yes, I tried with IP - same results.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you are doing perf test from one cloud service to another cloud service.

Azure load balancer does not throttle. It is an infrastructure components with extremely high limits. What could happen is that you may run our or ports. When you create outbound connections, we SNAT to source VIP. Since you SNAT, you get a limit of 64K ports.
The best to verify this is to associate a public IP to your VM running the perf test (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/) then run your test again

Yves